# Построение DSM матрицы для Jar-файлов

Tags: java, eclipse, матрицы, uml

Мне нужно построить матрицу DSM-матрицу для Jar файлов (DSMForJars).

https://dsmweb.org/sequencing-a-dsm

https://www.uml-diagrams.org/artifact.html

**Задание следующее**:
Для заданного классификатора (Classifier) мне нужно выдать атрифакт (Artifact) (jar-файл) в котором он содержится. Т.е. мне на вход дают классификатор, а я должен буду получить артифакт файла, в котором находится мой класс.

```
public static Artifact getArtifact(Classifier cls) {
    return null;
}
```

Собственно, сам класс, в котором находится данный метод:

```
public class DSM4Jars {
    static List<Artifact> jars = new ArrayList<>();

    public static DSM dsm = new DSM(jars);

    public static void load(Model model) {
        Consumer<? super Element> action = e -> jars.add((Artifact) e);
        UMLUtil.walkAll(model, e -> true, e -> e instanceof Artifact, action);

        dsm = new DSM(jars);
        dsm.buildJars();
    }

/**
 * Для заданного классификатора выдать атрифакт (jar-файл)
 * в котором он содержится.
 * 
 * @param cls - классификатор.
 * @return найденный артифакт или null
 */

/*
 * Мне на вход дают классификатор, а я должен буду получить артефакт файла, в котором находится мой класс. 
 * Классификатор - это общий предок для класса, интерфейса, и перечисления*/
    public static Artifact getArtifact(Classifier cls) {

        for(Artifact jar: jars)
        {
            ???
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void dump(String dumpPath) {
        ...
    }

    public static void dumpArtifactPackages(String dumpPath) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я сам решил задачу.

```
public static Artifact getArtifact(Classifier cls) {

    for(Artifact jar: jars){

        List<String> list_strPackages = jar.getManifestations()
                   .stream()
                   .map(Manifestation::getUtilizedElement)
                   .map(PackageableElement::getNearestPackage)
                   .distinct()
                   .map(UMLUtil::getJavaName)
                   .filter(x -> x.equals(UMLUtil.getJavaName(cls.getNearestPackage())))
                   .collect( Collectors.toList() );

        if(list_strPackages != null && !list_strPackages.isEmpty())
        {
            return jar;
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```